# VB.NET - Search Between Dates And Also Search via Textbox

Tags: sql, database, vb.net, vb.net-2010

I'm Having problems setting these two functions in my program. Tried Several Tutorials but those didn't work. I'm using `vb.net Local Database`.

```
WHERE Date BETWEEN (?) AND (?)
```

In other tutorials, these code works fine. But for some reason I am unable to run this code in my program.

-- Screenshots Given Below --

[image: SQL Query Code]

[image: SQL Query Builder Execution Error]

[image: SQL Query Code Execution Error]

Comment: Which column(s) in your database are type `text`? Why are you using that data type at all, given that it has been deprecated for years? Is this an existing database that you don't have control over?

Comment: Whenever you have issues with SQL code, it's generally best to strip it back to the simplest code possible and then build it up step by step until it breaks in order to identify exactly where the issue is.  Also, if you can, work on the SQL in SSMS until you get it right, then copy it across.

Comment: @jmcilhinney Then what type should I use for Name? And No. This is not an existing database.

Comment: nvarchar and varchar for variable length strings. Look up SQL Server data types.

Comment: I am most interested in the data type (in the database) of the Date column. Date could be a reserved word therefore surround with [  ] . To me, it is much easier to dump TableAdapters and write my own code. Easier to control.

Comment: Those question marks are making me suspicious. Is this Access or SQL Server or some other database?

Comment: @Mary this is Access Database.

Comment: `Date` is a reserved word in SQL, you should surround it by `[ ]` if it's a MS Access database. And you shouldn't have named your column `Date` in the first place

Answer (score 0):

```
WHERE Date BETWEEN (@param1) AND (@param2)
```

Comment: Please read [answer] and [edit] your answer to contain an explanation as to why this code would actually solve the problem at hand. Always remember that you're not only solving the problem, but are also educating the OP and any future readers of this post.